# does "about in all directions" mean "approximately everywhere"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

does "about in all directions" mean "approximately everywhere"?

The void beyond our atmosphere is anything but empty, with particles whizzing **about in all directions**.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The verb is "to whizz about". In this case "about" has the meaning of "around"/"in the area"

In fact "about" can have the meaning, "in all directions", so the phrase could be construed as meaning, "particles whizzing in all directions in all directions"!

---

adverb

> used to indicate movement within an area: British "men were
> floundering about" synonyms around, here and there, to and fro, back
> and forth, from place to place, ... more
>
> Oxford Dictionaries